# how to get the standard deviation

Tags: java, loops, math

idk if i have to get the standard while in the loop or out of the loop.also can you help me understand why it is i do it inside the loop or out and what the difference is. also i know the standard deviation formula in this situation would be something like (input - average)^2 for the first then ++ for every value after then add all that up and divide by the count then square root that. im just not fully sure how to write it and where to put it

```
import java.util.Scanner; 

public class readFromKeyboard { 

    public static void main(String[] args) { 


        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in); 

        String inStr = input.next(); 
        int n; 
        int count=0; 
        int min = Integer.MAX_VALUE;
        int max = Integer.MIN_VALUE; 
        double average=0;
        int sum;
        double deviation = 0;

        while (!inStr.equals("EOL")) { 
          count++; 
          n = Integer.parseInt(inStr); 
          min = Math.min(min, n);
          max = Math.max(max, n);
          System.out.printf("%d ", n); 
          inStr = input.next(); 
          average += n;
        } 

        average = average/count;

        System.out.println("\n The average of these numbers is " + average);
        System.out.printf("The list has %d numbers\n", count); 
        System.out.printf("The minimum of the list is %d\n", min);
        System.out.printf("The maximum of the list is %d\n", max);


        input.close(); 


    } 
}
```

Comment: You can add a second loop to calculate the standard deviation based on your average.

Comment: should i write a loop that divides every number by the mean then squares it while the numbers are being input then adds them up divides by count then square roots it?

Comment: I'm not following. First let's make sure that we are talking about `standard deviation`, and not `population standard deviation` or `variance`.

Comment: i completely forgot there are two types of standard deviation. we want the population standard deviation

Comment: Btw what you described in your post is actually `variance`.

Comment: variance is what you have before you square root it right? i thought variance was every step above minus the final square root

Comment: Check out the definition https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_deviation

Comment: yes thats what i was trying to describe sorry for the confusion. how do i start my loop?

Answer (score 1):

Given that you already calculated `average`, now you can calculate the `standard deviation` for each number.

1. Create array `sd[]` to store the `standard deviation`.
2. For each number, `sd[i] = (average - input_i) ^ 2`

Calculate `variance`:

1. For each `standard deviation` in `sd[]`, add to a variable `temp`
2. Divide `temp` by total number of inputs

Calculate `population standard deviation`:

1. Square root `variance`